# How can I configure my database so that I can connect from any machine?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm new to Azure Create a database with your server to work as a team. but I have to add the IP to the firewalls of each one. The problem is that the IP changes and the IP must be updated. Do I need to know if there is another form of configuration to be able to access from any IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be advisable to have some sort of middle ware access the db and not your clients directly.

However if you want any IP to be able to connect to the db just add this entry to the firewall list:

Azure Portal -> Azure Sql Server-> Database-> set server firewall and add the following rule:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful. middleware would be great also to improve security

Answer (score 0):

As Joey Cai mentioned you can create a firewall rule to accept access from all IP addresses. However, we solved this issue by building an application that our users on the road run to update firewall rules for them and gain access to Azure SQL Database.

From C# you can access all Azure resources via Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent like this

```
// Create an authentication context to Azure and acquire a login token
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId");
var auth = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    "yourClientId", new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, 
                           AzureParts.Tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

// Build the client with the acquired token as a credential.
RestClient client = RestClient.Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .WithCredentials(azureCredentials)
                .Build();

// Authenticate against azure with the correct subscription to access.
var azure = Azure.Authenticate(client, AzureParts.Tenant)
                .WithSubscription("subscriptionId");

// Search for the sql server and add a firewall rule.
var sqlServer = azure.SqlServers.GetByResourceGroup("ResourceGroup", "servername");
sqlServer.FirewallRules.Define("LetMeIn").WithIPAddress("yourIp").Create();
```

Note that acquiring the login token via AcquireTokenAsync will open a login window and thus can not be used in an automated fashion. You could provide a token-cache with an already stored token if you want to only login once.

Comment: Where is AzureParts.Tenant from? I can't find any package that contains that.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/#:~:text=Fluent%201.37.1%20Provides%20management%20%28Fluent%29%20capabilities%20for%20Microsoft,Team%20does%20not%20provide%20support%20for%20this%20client.